# dotnet watch files other than *.cs files

Tags: .net-core, watch, .net-core-2.1

So I did a quick google search and everything I've found has simply mentioned how to setup the basic `dotnet watch` command. I have this working however I'm wondering if there is some way to have it watch more than just files with the `.cs` extension..

For instance when I make a configuration change to a `.json` file. I can't seem to find any documentation about this at all..

Comment: [The readme](https://github.com/aspnet/DotNetTools/blob/dev/src/dotnet-watch/README.md) tells you how to configure the watch items.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @Hans Passant for leading me to the answer.

For anyone else that lands here, the answer is documented here: https://github.com/aspnet/DotNetTools/blob/release/2.1/src/dotnet-watch/README.md

For my case adding something like the following node to my `.csproj` should do the trick.

```
<ItemGroup>
   <Watch Include="**\*.json" Exclude="node_modules\**\*.json;$(DefaultExcludes)" />
</ItemGroup>
```